# How to check which database roles can see `masked` columns?

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2016, dynamic-data-masking

In `SQL Server 2016 SP1` standard edition we can use [dynamic-data-masking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/dynamic-data-masking). The masking of data is controlled using the built-in security, for example:

```
REVOKE UNMASK TO user_who_cannot_see_senstive_data
```

Of course, this is not working for the users who are members of the `db_owner` database role.

Is there a list with security roles or cases showing when the `REVOKE UNMASK` is going to work?

I have found a [database engine permissions](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=229142) but it's too complicated and does not seem to show when data cannot be masked from a user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to check which database roles can see `masked` columns?

Normal query which checks for users permissions seems to do the trick

```
    select  princ.name
,       princ.type_desc
,       perm.permission_name
,       perm.state_desc
,       perm.class_desc
,       object_name(perm.major_id)
from    sys.database_principals princ
left join
        sys.database_permissions perm
on      perm.grantee_principal_id = princ.principal_id
```

I tested it on below sample script from msdn

```
CREATE TABLE Membership  
  (MemberID int IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,  
   FirstName varchar(100) MASKED WITH (FUNCTION = 'partial(1,"XXXXXXX",0)') NULL,  
   LastName varchar(100) NOT NULL,  
   Phone# varchar(12) MASKED WITH (FUNCTION = 'default()') NULL,  
   Email varchar(100) MASKED WITH (FUNCTION = 'email()') NULL);  

INSERT Membership (FirstName, LastName, Phone#, Email) VALUES   
('Roberto', 'Tamburello', '555.123.4567', 'RTamburello@contoso.com'),  
('Janice', 'Galvin', '555.123.4568', 'JGalvin@contoso.com.co'),  
('Zheng', 'Mu', '555.123.4569', 'ZMu@contoso.net');  

CREATE USER TestUser WITHOUT LOGIN;  
GRANT SELECT ON Membership TO TestUser;  


GRANT UNMASK TO TestUser;  
EXECUTE AS USER = 'TestUser';  
SELECT * FROM Membership;  
REVERT;
```

now querying gives me below result

[image]